# Heroku App Always Crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, crash

It's now been 48 hours since my heroku app has started crashing.
I don't honestly know what is making it crash, i've tried restarting it, changing the dynos and running `heroku run rake db:migrate` but none of these seem to work.

***These are my heroku logs***

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=serene-savannah-7550.herokuapp.com fwd="81.34.154.155" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-27T12:51:50+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK measure.current_transaction=26940 measure.db_size=56841336bytes measure.tables=23 measure.active-connections=3 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.85317 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=0.99704
2013-08-27T12:52:45+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK measure.current_transaction=26940 measure.db_size=56841336bytes measure.tables=23 measure.active-connections=3 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.85317 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=0.99704
2013-08-27T12:53:34.027760+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.website.com fwd="81.34.154.155" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-27T12:54:35.129270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.website.com fwd="81.34.154.155" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-27T12:54:36+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK measure.current_transaction=26940 measure.db_size=56841336bytes measure.tables=23 measure.active-connections=3 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.99998 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=1
2013-08-27T12:55:15.018337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.website.com fwd="81.34.154.155" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I have tried changing to 2 Dynos x1 and 1 Dyno x2 but it doesnt change anything
I have PostgreSQL Crane installed and set as my DATABASE_URL.

Why is it crashing and how could I fix this annoying error?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your app is repeatedly crashing (but you already knew that). Have you created migrations that haven't been run, yet?

Try `heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

If that doesn't work, try running the Rails console on Heroku to help diagnose the issue. Run `heroku run bundle exec rails console`.

Comment: Running `heroku run bundle exec rails console` told me what the error was. Turns out for some reason my app_controller had been deleted. 
Thank god for backups!

Comment: thanks for the tip about using heroku run console to debug this

Comment: Running `bundle exec rails console` showed me my error. In my case, it was a Devise configuration. 

Thanks a lot for the tip! :D